# Disabling console exceptions on meteor production app

Tags: javascript, exception, meteor, logging, production-environment

I use `meteor build`  to bundle my app so that it can be deployed. However, I've noticed that the developer console gets a LOT of exception messages, mostly from debug.js (specifically realated to autoform) While these exceptions are harmless, I am still required to have them not show up in the dev console. Is there a way to disable all these exceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: It's good practice to write code that doesn't produce copious console output. The best way is to go back to your code and clean it up. You are quite likely to fix some bugs along the way

Comment: I agree 100% to @Mikkel. A production app with exceptions is not a production app IMO.

Comment: I'll have to agree with @Mikkel. But the thing is, these exceptions are not being thrown by my code. It's coming from autoform as part of it's validation. Eg. When the form is still being generated, it is validating certain elements based on the Schema, which probably isn't yet available. After a few iterations, the form eventually load up properly and the exception messages stop.

Comment: Well the challenge is to prevent the errors. Can you disable autoform until the right moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to try, but they all comes with pros and cons:

- Wrap the code which generate exception inside `try {} catch(e) {}`, this way you will control which exceptions are shown but it requires quite a lot of modification on your code
- On browser, if exception messages are logged by `console.error` or `console.log` you could override these functions. This prevents anything to be shown in browser's console, but this may cause un-expected behaviors so I do not recommend you go this way
- Lastly, I think you should go back to your code and make sure all the exceptions are handled well. Because if your app throws many un-expected exceptions, it may not be production-ready